# SQL query: how to group items correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

could you please help to modify the following SQL query so that it would work in mySQL? Currently, the error message is that table t1 doesn't exist. I would like to get a table with columns "post_title", "name1", "url1".

If it helps then this query can be tested on a Wordpress CMS database

```
SELECT t1.post_title,
       (select meta_value from t1 where t1.meta_key='name1_class' limit 1) as name1,
       (select meta_value from t1 where t1.meta_key='url1_class' limit 1) as url1
  FROM (select pm.post_id as id, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value, p.post_title, t.slug from wp_2_postmeta pm
    inner join wp_2_posts p on pm.post_id = p.id
    inner join wp_2_term_relationships tr on tr.object_id = p.id    
    inner join wp_2_term_taxonomy tt on tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    inner join wp_2_terms t on t.term_id = tt.term_id
    where post_type='footercolumn' and post_status='publish' and pm.meta_key like '%class') t1
```

the subquery for t1 table in the "FROM" clause produces a dataset like this:

```
'id', 'meta_key',  'meta_value', 'post_title', 'slug' 
'18', 'name1_class', 'Our Work', 'Who we are', 'column1' 
'18', 'url1_class', '/work.html', 'Who we are', 'column1' 
'18', 'name1_class', 'Our Team', 'About', 'column2' 
'18', 'url1_class', 'team.html', 'About', 'column2
```

I would like the result table to be:

```
'title',      'name1',     'url1'
'Who we are', 'Our Work',  'work.html'
'About',      'Our Team',  'team.html'
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to emulate a CTE (common table expression) using subselects, but I can't quite think of a way to make that work.

The good news is that if you can use an aggregate to find the data, you don't need the subselect.

```
SELECT t1.post_title,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='name1_class' THEN meta_value END) as name1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='url1_class' THEN meta_value END) as url1
  FROM (select pm.post_id as id, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value, p.post_title, t.slug 
        from wp_2_postmeta pm
        inner join wp_2_posts p on pm.post_id = p.id
        inner join wp_2_term_relationships tr on tr.object_id = p.id    
        inner join wp_2_term_taxonomy tt 
           on tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        inner join wp_2_terms t on t.term_id = tt.term_id
        where post_type='footercolumn' and post_status='publish' and pm.meta_key 
              like '%class') t1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't even think you need the subqueries, you could rejoin the postmeta table twice to get the columns and simplify the query a bit:

```
SELECT       p.post_title
            ,pma.meta_value AS name1
            ,pmb.meta_value AS url1

FROM        wp_2_posts p

JOIN        wp_2_postmeta pma
ON          p.ID = pma.post_id
AND         pma.meta_key = 'name1_class'

JOIN        wp_2_postmeta pmb
ON          p.ID = pmb.post_id
AND         pmb.meta_key = 'url1_class'

JOIN        wp_2_term_relationships tr
ON          tr.object_id = p.id 

JOIN        wp_2_term_taxonomy tt 
ON          tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id

JOIN        wp_2_terms t 
ON          t.term_id = tt.term_id

WHERE       p.post_type='footercolumn'
AND         p.post_status='publish'
```

If some reason you had multiple `name1_class` or `url1_class` values per post that gave repeating post_title rows, add `GROUP BY` to eliminate that.

```
GROUP BY    post_title
```

If you were missing values due to `NULL` in `name1_class` or `url1_class` you could correct that by changing the JOIN on pma/pmb to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` is the default join type so there is no need to specify `INNER` in this case